# Javascript TypeError: JSON array object is undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting a perfectly created JSON object from server response.

For example:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "userId": 20410,
            "firstName": "Viral",
            "lastName": "Shah",
            "loginId": "viralp.shah@tcs.com",
            "userRole": 3
        },
        {
            "userId": 400881,
            "firstName": "Viral",
            "lastName": "Shah",
            "loginId": "viralpshah123@gmail.com",
            "userRole": 0
        },
        {
            "userId": 425622,
            "firstName": "Viral",
            "lastName": "Shah",
            "loginId": "viralpshah123@tcs-itontap.com",
            "userRole": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using this in JavaScript using AJAX like below:

```
var jsonobj2 = null;
var respObj = getSearchedWPUsers(firstname, lastname, loginid); //return json response
var len = respObj.length;
jsonobj2 = eval('(' + respObj + ')');


var tablehtml = "<table><tr><td><b>First Name</td><td><b>Last Name</td><td><b>Login Id</td><td><b>Editing Rights</td></tr><tr></tr>";

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  tablehtml = tablehtml + "<tr>";
  //--------------
  tablehtml = tablehtml + "<td>";
  tablehtml = tablehtml + jsonobj2.users[i].firstName;
  tablehtml = tablehtml + "</td>";
  //--------------
  tablehtml = tablehtml + "<td>";
  tablehtml = tablehtml + jsonobj2.users[i].lastName;
  tablehtml = tablehtml + "</td>";
  //--------------
  tablehtml = tablehtml + "<td>";
  tablehtml = tablehtml + jsonobj2.users[i].loginId;
  tablehtml = tablehtml + "</td>";
  //--------------
  tablehtml = tablehtml + "<td><b>";
  var role = jsonobj2.users[i].userRole;
  if (role == 1 || role == 2 || role == 3) tablehtml = tablehtml + "<a href ='javascript:removeXML(" + jsonobj2.users[i].userId + ")'><u><font color='red'>Revoke access</font></a> ";
  else tablehtml = tablehtml + "<a href ='javascript:generateXML(" + jsonobj2.users[i].userId + ")'><u><font color='blue'>Assign access</font></a> ";

  tablehtml = tablehtml + "</td>";
  tablehtml = tablehtml + "</tr>";

}
tablehtml = tablehtml + "</table>";


document.getElementById("TableHolder").innerHTML = tablehtml;

//--------------------------
```

It throws errors like below

> `TypeError: jsonobj2.users[i] is undefined`
>   `[Break On This Error]`
>   `tablehtml = tablehtml + jsonobj2.users[i].firstName;`

tried with `JSON.parse(serverresponse);` -- nothing happened

Please help

Comment: Are you sure `respObj` is what you think it is? It seems strange to *return* a value from a function making an Ajax call. Please show us what it contains.

Comment: Are you sure that `respObj` contains something? You might need to do `async: false` ajax in order to return something from ajax call. Because ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: Did you check what's in respObj in the firebug? Check firebug response.

Comment: getSearchedWPUsers(firstname, lastname, loginid); method is AJAX call method and it returns the json object fine I have pasted a sample response at the above of the post

respObj does return a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
jsonobj2 = eval('(' + respObj + ')');
var len = jsonobj2.users.length;
```

As I understand, `respObj` is a string that contains the JSON response, but it still needs to be parsed. So, if you do `respObj.length`, you're getting the length of the string, but not of the users array, properly. Also, I recommend you to parse this response using `JSON.parse` (whenever available by the browser) instead of using `eval`:

```
var respObj = getSearchedWPUsers(firstname, lastname, loginid);
var jsonobj2 = JSON.parse ? JSON.parse(respObj) : eval('(' + respObj + ')');
var len = respObj && respObj.users ? respObj.users.length : 0;
```

However, as Felix Kling and Aamir Adnan said, ajax calls are mostly asynchronous, so you might pass a callback function as argument, which will process the response as your will:

```
getSearchedWPUsers(firstname, lastname, loginid, function(respObj){
    var jsonobj2 = JSON.parse ? JSON.parse(respObj) : eval('(' + respObj + ')');
    var len = respObj && respObj.users ? respObj.users.length : 0;
    var tablehtml = "<table><tr><td><b>First Name</td><td><b>Last Name</td><td><b>Login Id</td><td><b>Editing Rights</td></tr><tr></tr>";

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        tablehtml = tablehtml + "<tr>";
        //--------------
        tablehtml = tablehtml + "<td>";
        tablehtml = tablehtml + jsonobj2.users[i].firstName;
        tablehtml = tablehtml + "</td>";
        //--------------
        tablehtml = tablehtml + "<td>";
        tablehtml = tablehtml + jsonobj2.users[i].lastName;
        tablehtml = tablehtml + "</td>";
        //--------------
        tablehtml = tablehtml + "<td>";
        tablehtml = tablehtml + jsonobj2.users[i].loginId;
        tablehtml = tablehtml + "</td>";
        //--------------
        tablehtml = tablehtml + "<td><b>";
        var role = jsonobj2.users[i].userRole;
        if (role == 1 || role == 2 || role == 3)
            tablehtml = tablehtml + "<a href ='javascript:removeXML(" + jsonobj2.users[i].userId + ")'><u><font color='red'>Revoke access</font></a> ";

        else tablehtml = tablehtml + "<a href ='javascript:generateXML(" + jsonobj2.users[i].userId + ")'><u><font color='blue'>Assign access</font></a> ";

        tablehtml = tablehtml + "</td>";
        tablehtml = tablehtml + "</tr>";

    }
    tablehtml = tablehtml + "</table>";

    document.getElementById("TableHolder").innerHTML = tablehtml;
});
```

Comment: It worked.
Understood the mistake with length.
Thanks a lot Mark